# node.jsでwebサーバーを作ったのだがウェブページにアクセスできない

Tags: node.js

お世話になります。

node.jsでwebサーバーを作ったのですが、ウェブページにアクセスできません。（ブラウザに表示できません）

ファイル名 server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('hello world');
    res.end();
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log("server listening ...");
```

ターミナルでの表示結果

```
[vagrant@localhost nodejs]$ node server.js

server listening ...
```

localhost:1337でアクセスしたのですが、ブラウザ(chrome）にはこのウェブページにアクセスできませんと表示されてしまいます。

アドバイスを頂いた通りを実行したところ下記の問題が発生しました。

```
[vagrant@localhost nodejs]$ curl http://localhost:1337/
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

常時プロキシを設定するには以下の通りにする良いと書いてあったので試してみましたがviが書き込み禁止と認識しているみたいです。

```
# vi /etc/bashrc

(viで開いたので、一番最後の行とかに以下を追記)

alias curl="curl -x http://proxy.jpn.hp.com:8080/"

(:wqで保存して終了)
```

chmodを使用してファイルの変更をするみたいなのですが、どのファイル(bashrc?）にどのようにして書き込むのか教えて下さい。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 具体的にどのようなURLに接続しようとしたのでしょうか？ http://localhost:1337/ につなげばメッセージが出ると思いますが。表示できなかったなら具体的なエラーコードなりを書いてもらえると調査がしやすいと思います。

Comment: @mjy さんの回答通り、 **node server.js &** を実行してから curl http://localhost:1337/ を実行していますか？更新された回答を見る限り、一旦server.jsを停止しているように見えますが。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます！
ターミナルに表示されました！！

[vagrant@localhost nodejs]$ server listening ...
curl http://localhost:1337
hello world[vagrant@localhost nodejs]$

ブラウザには表示することはできないのでしょうか？
また、node server.jsを起動する前には既存のプロセスを下記のように記入して消さなければならないのでしょうか？新たに記述した際など更新する際などどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか？
オススメの参考サイト等があれば教えていただけると嬉しいです！

sudo kill -9 (4~5桁の番号)

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: nodeはイベントキューが空にならないと停止しない構造なのでserverのlisten()が止まればプロセスは終了します。
それと、自分が生成したプロセスは特権を使わなくても停止できます。この場合kill %と打てば止まります。やたら特権を使うのは好ましくありません。詳しくはshell,job-controlをキーワードに調べてみてください。

Comment: ちょっと環境を教えて頂きたいのですが、恐らく Virtualbox + vagrant で Linuxな感じですよね？その vagrant からホスト(WindowsPCとかでしょうか)にPingは飛びますか？飛ばなければ node.js から一旦離れて仮想環境のネットワーク設定を見直された方がよいと思います。また、毎回手動で node を起動したりするのが面倒であれば、node.js スクリプトをデーモン化するツールで forever というものがありますので、そちらをお試しください。 https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Answer (score 1):

仮想環境で実行されているようですので、その環境のネットワークの問題かもしれません。  
まずは下記のように同じ環境からのアクセスを試して見ましょう。

```
node server.js &
curl http://localhost:1337/
```